# can any one help me in appending the data to the plist file?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have tried this code to copy my data to plist but its not working in the case of appending .can any one suggest me a good method for appending the data?
    NSMutableDictionary *nameDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

```
NSString *plistPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"listNew" ofType:@"plist"];
[nameDictionary setValue:nameEntered.text forKey:@"name"];
[nameDictionary setValue:company.text forKey:@"company"];
[nameDictionary setValue:designation.text forKey:@"designation"];

// create dictionary with values in UITextFields
NSMutableArray *plist = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
if (plist == nil) plist = [NSMutableArray array];
[plist addObject:nameDictionary];
[plist writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
UIAlertView *tellErr = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:@"succsefully created" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[tellErr show];
nameEntered.text=@"";
company.text=@"";
designation.text=@"";
```

Comment: When you say its not working, are you seeing a crash or does the array simply not have the dictionary you expected to be added to the end?  From what I see, the code you have above looks fine.

Comment: when i am trying to insert it for the first time it removes whole data from the plist or if i am viewing the list and then going for the insertion the it crashes

Comment: if your question is answered please mark it as answered with green check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [+[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedArchiver/archiveRootObject%3atoFile%3a) to archive the Array object to file. And use [+[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/unarchiveObjectWithFile%3a) to unarchive it.

Comment: What benefit does using `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:toFile:]` offer above what he's already doing?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
NSString *plistPath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"listNew" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
if (plist == nil) plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[plist setObject:nameEntered.text forKey:@"name"];
[plist setObject:company.text forKey:@"company"];
[plist setObject:designation.text forKey:@"designation"];
[plist writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

... etc ...

Of course, this depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: but this will override the old data.I want the newly entered data to be appended to the old data

Comment: This will not override the old data. However, there is an error in it which I'll fix in a minute or so.

Comment: Allright, the error is fixed. dictionayWithContentsOfFile shoul alloc and init a dictionary and read the contents of the file into the dictionary. Then the plist values are in the dictionary. Then the 3 new values are added and after that the full dictionary is written to the same file name. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to the application main bundle in iOS.  You must copy the property list file to a writable directory; then you can read it, modify it, and rewrite it.

Comment: you are telling me to fetch the plist file from the document directory or some folder like that right?

Comment: Right, your code segment above reads the plist, presumably pre-populated with data from the main bundle.  But you cannot save a modified version of the file back to the main bundle.  You would have to save it to the documents directory, etc.  It is common for apps to copy resources that need to be modified to the app support directory or docs directory on initial launch for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Ok dude, here is the code that you need. I am using this in an existing iOS program

first check to see if there is any info in the dictionary to begin with

```
static BOOL dicIsNULL = YES;

....

//initialize the variable
dicIsNULL = YES;


//READ FILE
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *stringsPlistPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"listNew.plist"];

        dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:stringsPlistPath];

        //Check if this dic has values
        for (id key in dictionary) 
        {
             //NSLog(@"listNew.plist file has values");
            dicIsNULL = NO;
            break;
        }
```

Now do the following depending upon the dictonary had already been created or not. Add your values in the dictionary, this is just a sample code.

```
if (dicIsNULL == YES)
        {
            //NSLog(@"dictionary is NULL");

            dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:tempArray, infoKeyStr,  textTitleField1.text, titleKeyStr, userSelectedCatStr, catKeyStr, nil];

        }

        if (dicIsNULL == NO)
        {
            //NSLog(@"dictionary is NOT null");

            dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:stringsPlistPath];
            [dictionary setObject: tempArray forKey: infoKeyStr];
            [dictionary setObject: textTitleField1.text forKey: titleKeyStr];
            [dictionary setObject: userSelectedCatStr forKey: catKeyStr];
        }
```

hope this helps you out.